# using sed with escape characters in a variable

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How do I do a `sed` using a variable with escape characters?

This is my file:

```
$ cat file1.txt
abcdefg
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


some more text


<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


some more text

</head>
```

I am trying to wite the following command(whcih works in the command line using an escape character)

```
$ sed 's/<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team<\/p>/99999/g' file1.txt
abcdefg
99999


some more text


99999


some more text

</head>
```

in a script using variables but the escape characters or other are getting the better of me:

This is my attempt at my script where I can get `grep` to work using a variable but I cannot get `sed` to work. Can anyone help me?

```
#!/bin/bash
###
# this is the text i want to find 
# <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
# and this is the text I want to replace depending on the year
# <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015. Core Team</p>

echo "hello this is a script to find a string and replace it with a string"

#s1='<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>'  without escape characters
s1='<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>'
s2='<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015. Core Team</p>'

echo "s1="
echo "$s1"

echo "s2="
echo "$s2"


echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n\n\----------------\n\n\n\n\n\---------------"

grep "$s1" file1.txt #> file2.txt

sed 's/$s1/123/g' file1.txt #> file2.txt
#cat file2.txt


echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n\n\----------------\n\n\n\n\n\---------------"
```

---

**-----------Edit1 below-Further explanation and/or For my reference-----------------**

---

This is the file i want to sed on:

```
$ cat file1.txt
abcdefg
123
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


some more text


<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


some more text

</head>
```

this is my script

```
$ cat insertText2.sh
#!/bin/bash
###
# this is the text i want to find
# <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
# and this is the text I want to replace depending on the year
# <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015. Core Team</p>

echo "hello this is a script to find a string and replace it with a string"

#s1='<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>'  without escape characters
s1='<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>'
s2='<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015. Core Team</p>'

echo "s1="
echo "$s1"

echo "s2="
echo "$s2"


echo -e "\n\n-------grep on file1.txt--\n\n---------------"

grep "$s1" file1.txt #> file2.txt

echo -e "\n\n-------cat on file1.txt--\n\n---------------"

cat file1.txt

echo -e "\n\n-------sed on file1.txt--\n\n---------------"

#sed "s/$s1/123/g" file1.txt #> file2.txt
#sed "s|$s1|123|g" file1.txt #> file2.txt
sed "s|$s1|$s2|g" file1.txt #> file2.txt
#sed 's/123/ABC/g' file1.txt #> file2.txt
#cat file2.txt
```

this is the output of my script

```
$ ./insertText2.sh file1.txt
hello this is a script to find a string and replace it with a string
s1=
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
s2=
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015. Core Team</p>


-------grep on file1.txt--

---------------
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


-------cat on file1.txt--

---------------
abcdefg
123
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


some more text


<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


some more text

</head>


-------sed on file1.txt--

---------------
abcdefg
123
<p class="text-muted"><p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>copy; 2015. Core Team</p>


some more text


<p class="text-muted"><p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>copy; 2015. Core Team</p>


some more text

</head>
```

but this is not doing what i want, it is replacing 
`<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>`

with
`<p class="text-muted"><p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>copy; 2015. Core Team</p>`

so maybe this has something to do with my escape characters?

Comment: Use double quotes for variable expansion: `sed "s/$s1/123/g"`

Comment: ^^ Plus, since your patterns would likely contain `/` character, you would need to use a different delimiter (say `|`) for sed : e.g. `sed "s|$s1|123|g"`

Comment: good to know. I was using the single quotes `'` as I have double quotes `"` in my variable. And I tried using `|` but that does not fully work

Answer (score 0):

the solution I came up with was this 
`sed "s|$s1|$s2|g" file1.txt` and I had to use an escape character `\` on the ampersand `&` in the variable.

this is the file that I am searching:

```
$ cat file1.txt
abcdefg
123
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
<p basic2014="test">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
some more text


<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
<p basic2014="test">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>

some more text

</head>
```

This is the script that I am running:

```
$ cat insertText3.sh
#!/bin/bash
###
# this is the text i want to find
# <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
# and this is the text I want to replace depending on the year
# <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015. Core Team</p>

echo -e "hello this is a script to find a string and replace it with a string:\n"

#s1='<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>'  without escape characters ## what I want to find and replace
s1='<p class="text-muted">\&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>' ## need the single quotes here
s2='<p class="text-muted">\&copy; 2015. Core Team</p>'

echo "this is what I want to find (note the escape character(\) in the variable to escape the ampersand(&) )(s1)="
echo "$s1"
echo -e "\n"

echo "this is what I want it to be replaced with (s2)="
echo "$s2"


echo -e "\n\n-------grep on file1.txt--\n\n---------------"

grep "$s1" file1.txt #> file2.txt

echo -e "\n\n-------cat on file1.txt--\n\n---------------"

cat file1.txt

echo -e "\n\n-------sed on file1.txt--\n\n---------------"


sed "s|$s1|$s2|g" file1.txt #> file2.txt   works ## double quotes gives an error, single quotes runs with no errrors but does not alter the text
                                                ## because I have forward/backslash in the variable i use |

# #sed -i.bak2 "$c2" *.html
```

This is the output of the script run:

```
$ ./insertText3.sh
hello this is a script to find a string and replace it with a string:

this is what I want to find (note the escape character(\) in the variable to escape the ampersand(&) )(s1)=
<p class="text-muted">\&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


this is what I want it to be replaced with (s2)=
<p class="text-muted">\&copy; 2015. Core Team</p>


-------grep on file1.txt--

---------------
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>


-------cat on file1.txt--

---------------
abcdefg
123
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
<p basic2014="test">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
some more text


<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
<p basic2014="test">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>

some more text

</head>


-------sed on file1.txt--

---------------
abcdefg
123
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015. Core Team</p> ##<< 2014 has changed to 2015
<p basic2014="test">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
some more text


<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015. Core Team</p> ##<< 2014 has changed to 2015
<p basic2014="test">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>

some more text

</head>
```